# qtcreator tray icon under window does not show up when deployed

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt-creator

i'am trying to deploy a QT application made in QT Creator which goes back to system tray when closed.

I have made a svg tray icon, when i run it from QT Creator, either in debug and in release mode under Window 7, the tray icon shows up, but when i copy everything to another directory to make a distributable archive from it, the tray icon does not show up anymore.

Of course i search already for solutions, but everything i have found yet, i have made.

So what i have:

trayicon.svg file in project root

- qrc file created, adding trayicon.svg into the resource files root
- in project .pro file: RESOURCES += resources.qrc
- copied binary + necessary dll's to target directory
- copied QT plugins imageformats/* to target dir imageformats
- added QApplication a(argc, argv); a.addLibraryPath(a.applicationDirPath()); to main.cpp

that is everything i found so far, but still the system tray icon is not showing up

What am i missing?

(current qt 4.8 + current qtcreator by the way)

@netrom

code in MainWindow : QMainWindow constructor:

```
trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
showAction = new QAction(tr("&Show"), this);
connect(showAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(show()));
quitAction = new QAction(tr("&Quit"), this);
connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
trayIconMenu->addAction(showAction);
trayIconMenu->addSeparator();
trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);
trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this, SLOT(iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":trayicon.svg"));
trayIcon->show();
```

Comment: Could you show in code how you use the icon?

Comment: Try checking what `QFileInfo(":trayicon.svg").size()` yields when you deploy. The image is actually compiled into the application so it should be able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create iconegines directory in your app directory (for example: c:\MyApp\iconengines).
2. Copy qsvgicon.dll to this new directory (for example: c:\MyApp\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll) from qt plugins directory (in my case it's c:\qt\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll).
3. Copy QtSvg.dll to your app directory (for example: c:\MyApp\Qt5Svg.dll) from Qt bin directory (in my case it's c:\qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\Qt5Svg.dll).

P.S. I know I'm late, this answer is for those who will google same problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding this even though it was much later.  I had this same problem and found that all I needed was the Qt5Svg.dll.  I did not include the iconengine folder or the qsvgicon.dll.     Many other DLLs cause the program to show error messages.  However the Qt5SVG.dll just silently doesn't render any svgs.

Answer (score 0):

Again, way later for DuckDuckGo-ers:

If your icon is not in `.svg` you might need another solution. For my `.ico` system tray icon I had to copy `<path-to-qt>\plugins\imageformats` into the application folder. Actually only `qico.dll` was needed in that folder in my case, but you get my drift.